# Get data from remote mysql through ssh with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need access a Mysql db on a remote server, but have to use a ssh tunnel. Without python, I can access the db by the sql managemen client. With a python code, I use the sqlalchemy and sshtunnel. sshtunnel should work, but I can't get any data using read_sql. Here is the script I used:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sshtunnel
import pandas as pd

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (ssh_host, ssh_port),
    ssh_username=ssh_user,
    ssh_pkey =private_key,
    remote_bind_address=(mysql_host, mysql_port)
    ) as server:

    print('Server connected via SSH') 

    local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
    engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}:{}/my_db'.format(mysql_user, mysql_password, '127.0.0.1', local_port), echo=True)

    query = 'select count(*) from asset'

    data = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

It runs and will not stop. Actually I only get some information, but I don't know the mean and what I should do to get some right data. 
Here is the information returned:

```
Server connected via SSH

2019-03-24 22:42:47,316 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'

2019-03-24 22:42:47,317 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}

2019-03-24 22:42:47,637 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'

2019-03-24 22:42:47,638 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}

2019-03-24 22:42:48,587 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()

2019-03-24 22:42:48,587 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}

2019-03-24 22:42:49,239 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1

2019-03-24 22:42:49,240 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}

2019-03-24 22:42:49,571 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1

2019-03-24 22:42:49,572 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}

2019-03-24 22:42:50,022 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine DESCRIBE `select count(*) from asset`

2019-03-24 22:42:50,023 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}

2019-03-24 22:42:50,144 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK

2019-03-24 22:42:50,582 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select count(*) from asset

2019-03-24 22:42:50,583 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
```

Comment: accessing a database on a remote server via ssh just seems like bad design/practice

Comment: I also think so. however it is a policy, I have to follow. Before accessing via ssh, my script worked. now not.

Comment: Question is still there. However, I can access the remote db using pymysql and sshtunnel. I still don't know why sqlalchemy doesn't work here.

Comment: Newbie here. Why is it bad practice? I want to run my python script to populate a database on a remote linux server and though that SSH would increase security. What would be a good practice to achieve that? Thanks